# Undefined index: error

Tags: php

i am a beginner in php,i am facing a problem with the following code. it shows undefined index error."Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\phpmyadmin_practise\member.php on line 7
you must be login!".i can't understand what shoul i do.

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username'])
{
echo "Welcome,".$_SESSION['username']."!<br> <a href ='logout.php'> Logout </a> <br> <a href='changepassword.php'> changepassword </a> <br>";
}
else
{
    die("you must be login!");
}
```

?>

Answer (score 3):

`username` is not set.
 you should check variable with [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function before using them

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

Comment: @webrider- What do you mean by does not work. Is still there the same error?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the page for the first time, `$_SESSION['username']` will not be set (the key `username` does not exist). But you try to access it, so you get an error.

Use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

I hope you also have some kind of login page where the user is actually able to log in. `die("you must be login!");` will terminate the current script. If this is the only page you have, `$_SESSION['username']` will never be set.

And in production, you should not use `die` anyway. Create a proper error message on your page.

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['username'] is undefined.
try this condition:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
```